# moebius and powers. how do they behave?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

Suppose $f(n)=q^n$, where $q$ is an integer $>2$. (In the original formulation, $q$ should have been a prime, but I think it doesn't really matter)

Define the function
$$
g(n) = \sum_{d|n} \mu\left(\frac nd \right)f(d)
$$
that, by moebius inversion, is equivalent to
$$
f(n) = \sum_{d|n} g(d).
$$

Is it true that $n|g(n)$? 
I verified it for primes and powers of primes. Is it true in general? Probably the way to go is to apply the multiplicative property.

Comment: Solved it. It was a simple CRT

Comment: Post your own answer then. That way it can serve as a resource for others in the future, it will remove this question from the “unresolved” list, and you might even earn some rep for it.